# Biggest TableQuery on Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I want to get all the vehicles from an azure table, that have a status of "Complete" and a VehicleId from a list I have (around 4k GUIDs, right now).

I've combined the filters for the ParitionKey and the status column to get all the completed vehicles. Now I've looped through the ids list and I've added each VehicleId with the "or" operator.

```
i.e: ((PartitionKey = Vehicle) AND (Status = Complete)) AND ((VehicleId = xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx OR VehicleId = xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx) OR VehicleId = xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx) etc.
```

The result of this is a query that I use to call the storage (type string).

The resulted query is too big to be stored in a string type, therefore it's being cut.
I was wondering if there is any way to interrogate the AzureStorage with this kind of query. (The desired outcome is to get all the vehicles in a minimum number of calls).

Comment: Can you please edit your question and explain what you mean by `My issue is that the end result is too big, so the query is being cut down`.

Comment: Did I make myself clear? :D

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the query is cut off because it is too big. Correct?

Comment: Yes. I've tried to create multiple queries with 100 ids each, but I still query the storage 40 times. I was wondering if there is a different way for this without querying the storage so many times